# How to resolve typescript Redux connect error ActionCreatorsMapObject

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, redux

Have error with typescript

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/components/profile/userProfile/_userMain.tsx:130:37 
    TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof "/usr/src/app/src/js/src/app/redux/actions/sessionActions"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionCreatorsMapObject'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/components/profile/userProfile/_userMain.tsx:133:124 
    TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof UserProfileMain' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<(state: any) => any> | StatelessComponent<(state: any) => any>'.
  Type 'typeof UserProfileMain' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<(state: any) => any>'.
    Type 'typeof UserProfileMain' provides no match for the signature '(props: ((state: any) => any) & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'
```

Is it possible to fix this without decorators? ( @connect )

```
interface IActions {
    avatarUpload: (file:any) => void;
}

export interface IMainProps {
    auth: number,
    actions: IActions
}

class UserProfileMain extends React.Component<IMainProps, any> {
    constructor(props:any){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            files: [],
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(<div />)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state:any):any => {
    return {
        auth: state.authStatus.data.user.id,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any):any => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(sessionActions, dispatch) //First error (130:37)
    };
}
export default connect<typeof mapStateToProps, typeof mapDispatchToProps, IMainProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserProfileMain); //second error (133:124)
```

Already tried with `UserProfileMain as any` but got other bunch of errors

Maybe you know some best practice for that

Hope your support

Comment: Where is sessionActions defined? Can you please show this? It's difficult to be sure of what exactly is wrong without seeing all of the code.

Answer (score 8):

You need to change your

```
actions: bindActionCreators(sessionActions, dispatch)
```

line to

```
actions: bindActionCreators<any>(sessionActions, dispatch)
```

or something more specific because the redux typescript definitions are using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

[See the redux typescript definitions here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts#L343-L355).

The generic type in the <> should be the same type of sessionActions, which is also the return value of the bindActionCreators() function call.

Answer (score 2):

You might need

```
bindActionCreators<any, any>
```